# Adding residue IDs to a numpy array consisting of time series data of water coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, molecule, mdanalysis

I got this script for generating time series data of water molecules, and I want to add one more header row to that generated matrix with residue IDs of water molecules. Could anybody help with with reworking this script? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import MDAnalysis as mda

u = mda.Universe(PSF, DCD)
water_oxygens = u.select_atoms("name OW")

# pre-allocate the array for the data
data = np.zeros((u.trajectory.n_frames, water_oxygens.n_atoms + 1))

for i, ts in enumerate(u.trajectory):
   data[i, 0] = ts.time                          # store current time
   data[i, 1:] = water_oxygens.positions[:, 2]   # extract all z-coordinates
```

Comment: Most MDAnalysis developers and users look at questions posted in the user list/group https://groups.google.com/group/mdnalysis-discussion – you typically get a quicker answer there.

Comment: Okay, but you wrote this piece of code , can you also suggest any function or keywords for extracting residue ids of water molecules  ?

Comment: btw. Just because someone helped you does not mean you're entitled to further help. It's inconsiderate.

Comment: I am asking a question on this platform. Is not this platform for beginners like us to ask question and try to be more clearer about the problem? isn't it?

Comment: We welcome beginners asking questions. But it is really difficult to split time answering questions between different platforms. The MDAnalysis developers made a choice to prefer our own mailing lists over stackoverflow, ResearchGate or whatever else is out there. If we get to it, we might answer on S/O but ultimately we always recommend you go to the mailing list/google forum. In our experience, the forum is a better venue to solve problems in an interactive manner than S/O: it gives faster results for users and costs developers less time for better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adjusted code example. You might need to install the package `MDAnalysisTests` to run it:

```
import numpy as np
import MDAnalysis as mda
from MDAnalysisTests.datafiles import waterPSF, waterDCD

u = mda.Universe(waterPSF, waterDCD)
water_oxygens = u.select_atoms("name OH2")

# pre-allocate the array for the data
# one extra row for the header water residue IDs
data = np.zeros((u.trajectory.n_frames + 1, water_oxygens.n_atoms + 1))

# initialise the water residue IDs
data[0, 0] = np.NaN # the time column
data[0, 1:] = water_oxygens.atoms.resids

for i, ts in enumerate(u.trajectory, start=1):
   data[i, 0] = ts.time                          # store current time
   data[i, 1:] = water_oxygens.positions[:, 2]   # extract all z-coordinates
```